# After installing Ubuntu I no longer have the option to start Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows, bootloader

I have just installed Ubuntu for the first time. I followed the steps for partitioning and root directories as recommended. However, when I partitioned the /dev/sda1 was green and the disk did not recognize Windows 7. After installation, the Ubuntu was orange. When I reboot I am not given a choice of operating system: instead it goes straight to Ubuntu. How do I change this so I can access Windows 7 again?

Comment: @papukaija isn't it the other way round?

Comment: That question is older, so I thought that it was better that way, though the answer in this question is clearer than the answers in the other question. Feel free to mark it as a duplicate either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Boot-Repair: [Boot-Repair instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you installed Ubuntu 13.04, here is what you can try.  Boot from the Ubuntu 13.04 LiveCD.  Open Gparted by typing it in the Dash.  When it loads you should see all the partitions that are on the hard drive. Linux partitions will be EXT4 and the windows partitions will probably be NTFS.

Look at the list of partitions and see which one is the Linux partition, and look at the Mount Points of the partitions. You should see one with a `/` under Mount Point with a file system of EXT4, and look to see the name of it. In my case as per the images below of terminal, and Gparted its called `/dev/sda1` (yours may be different).  Open Terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

(Change the XY to match the name of your Linux partition).

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sdXY
```

Once done close terminal and any other open windows, and reboot.  Make sure that you remove the LiveCD.

Once rebooted, open Terminal and type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

When you it displays Done, reboot and you should be able to boot into windows again.

Answer (score -1):

I presume you have deleted your windows 7 loader from your MBR, Boot repair should help solving the issue.

Try this post
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10871917#post10871917